# Unity Animation - Shifting Position Unexpectedly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm learning Unity right now, and I want to animate a sprite of Mario running.

- I found a spritesheet and have cut out 3 images.
- I select my Mario game object and create a new animation
- In the animation window, I put in 3 spites at the times I want to animation the run
- When I press play, Mario is running, however he is also shifting position a little bit in the X direction but then resetting as the animation loops.

Why would my Mario object be shifting a little bit as part of the animation cycle? Where would I look to see an attached property or behavior that is causing him to do this? Maybe I moved the object while I had record on? I deleted all the associated animation objects and recreated them but Mario is still moving.

Comment: In your animator, uncheck `Apply root motion`. This tells the animator that you're going to apply the position and rotation through a script.

Comment: @varunkaustubh, we're on the right track! I uncheck that checkbox, however it's slightly different now. Instead of Mario taking a step forward, he's now taking a step backwards! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had a pivot point created on a single frame of the sprites. This would screw it up.